# Can I get Moldovan nationality by marriage?

Tags: citizenship, dual-citizenship

I am a Syrian citizen who has been married to a Moldovan woman for 6 years now. We have 2 children under 18 years old.

I lived in Moldova for 2 weeks only. Is it possible for me to have Moldovan citizenship because of my marriage or son?

Thanks.

Comment: The [Moldovan citizenship law (2003 version) is here](http://www.legislationline.org/download/action/download/id/6568/file/Moldova_Citizenship_Law_2000_am2003_eng.pdf). It says 3 years of marriage to a Moldovan is sufficient to qualify for naturalization, but I don't know if the 3 years must be in Moldova (it doesn't say that). You do need to speak the local language and renounce your former citizenship.